# Understanding why process stops receiving messages

Tags: erlang, timeout, trace

I have a situation where i have 3 processes:

- one process acting as a dispatcher for messages:  `server`
- one process acting as a supervisor (for a worker):  `monitor`
- one process acting as a worker that notifies supervisor when done: `worker`

The `server` sends a request to monitor and the `monitor` first checks if `worker` is busy.If busy, `monitor` enqueues the message (if capacity is not reached) or else forwards it to `worker`.
When the worker finishes processing it notifies both the client , and also the `monitor`

My problem is that my worker process stops responding after processing the first message

```
-module(mq).
-compile(export_all).

-record(monstate,{
    queue,
    qc,
    wpid,
    free=true,
    wref,
    init=false,
    frun=false
}).
-record(sstate,{
    init=false,
    mpid=null,
    mref=null
}).

-define(QUEUE_SIZE,5).
-define(PROC_SLEEP,2000).


createProcess({M,F,A})->
    Pid=spawn(M,F,[A]),
    Ref=erlang:monitor(process,Pid),
    {Pid,Ref}.

start()->
    spawn(?MODULE,server,[#sstate{init=false}]).

server(State=#sstate{init=I})when I=:=false ->
    {MPid,MRef}=createProcess({?MODULE,monitor,#monstate{init=false}}),
    server(State#sstate{init=true,mpid=MPid,mref=MRef});

server(State=#sstate{mpid=MPid,mref=MRef})->
    receive
           {From,state}->From ! State,
                            server(State);
           {From,Message}-> MPid ! {request,{From,Message}},
                            server(State);
                
            {'DOWN',MRef,process,MPid,_}-> {NewMPid,NewMRef}=createProcess({?MODULE,monitor,#monstate{init=false}}),
                                            server(State#sstate{mpid=NewMPid,mref=NewMRef});
            _ ->exit(invalid_message)
                                    
    end.
  

tryEnqueue(Message,MState=#monstate{queue=Q,qc=C}) when C<?QUEUE_SIZE->
    NewQueue=queue:in(Message,Q),
    {queued,MState#monstate{qc=C+1,queue=NewQueue}};
tryEnqueue(_,MState)->{queue_full,MState}.

monitor(MState=#monstate{wpid=_,wref=_,init=I}) when I=:= false ->
    {WorkerPid,WorkerRef}=createProcess({?MODULE,worker,self()}),
    monitor(MState#monstate{wpid=WorkerPid,wref=WorkerRef,init=true,qc=0,queue=queue:new(),frun=true});

monitor(MState=#monstate{wpid=W,free=F,wref=Ref,queue=Q,qc=C,frun=R})->
    receive
        
        {request,{From ,Message}} ->  
                                       {Result,NewState}=tryEnqueue({From,Message},MState),
                                        case Result of 
                                            queue_full -> From ! {queue_full,Message};
                                            _ -> ok
                                        end,
                                        case R of
                                            true -> self() ! {worker,{finished,R}},
                                                    monitor(NewState#monstate{frun=false});
                                            false -> monitor(NewState#monstate{frun=false})
                                        end;
                                       

        {worker,{finished,_}}-> case queue:out(Q) of
                                    {{_,Element},Rest} -> W ! Element,
                                                    monitor(MState#monstate{free=false,queue=Rest,qc=C-1});
                                    {empty,Rest} -> monitor(MState#monstate{free=true,queue=Rest})
                                end;

        {'DOWN',Ref,process,_,_}->
             {NewWorkerPid,NewWorkerRef}=createProcess({?MODULE,worker,self()}),
             monitor(MState#monstate{wpid=NewWorkerPid,wref=NewWorkerRef,free=true});

        _->exit(invalid_message)

    end.

worker(MPid)->
    receive 
        {From,MSG} ->
            timer:sleep(?PROC_SLEEP),
            From ! {processed,MSG},
            MPid ! {worker,{finished,MSG}},
            worker(MPid);
        _ ->exit(bad_msg)
    end.
```

**Usage**

```
2> A=mq:start().
<0.83.0>
3> A ! {self(),aa}.
{<0.76.0>,aa}
4> flush().
Shell got {processed,aa}
ok
5> A ! {self(),aa}.
{<0.76.0>,aa}
6> flush().
ok
```

I have added a tracer to see what is happening:

```
10> dbg:tracer().
{ok,<0.96.0>}
11> dbg:p(new,[sos,m]).
{ok,[{matched,nonode@nohost,0}]}
```

**First run**:

```
14> A ! {self(),aa}.
(<0.100.0>) << {<0.76.0>,aa}     // message received my server 
(<0.100.0>) <0.101.0> ! {request,{<0.76.0>,aa}}   //message forwarded by server to monitor
{<0.76.0>,aa}
(<0.101.0>) << {request,{<0.76.0>,aa}}         
15> (<0.101.0>) <0.101.0> ! {worker,{finished,true}} //monitor starting the cycle
15> (<0.101.0>) << {worker,{finished,true}}  
15> (<0.101.0>) <0.102.0> ! {<0.76.0>,aa}  // monitor sending message to worker
15> (<0.102.0>) << {<0.76.0>,aa}
15> (<0.105.0>) <0.62.0> ! {io_request,<0.105.0>,
                           #Ref<0.3226054513.2760638467.167990>,
                           {get_until,unicode,
                               ["15",62,32],
                               erl_scan,tokens,
                               [1,[text]]}}
15> (<0.102.0>) << timeout                      //worker getting timeout ??
15> (<0.102.0>) <0.76.0> ! {processed,aa}    //worker sends to self() thje message
15> (<0.102.0>) <0.101.0> ! {worker,{finished,aa}}   //worker notifies monitor to update state
15> (<0.101.0>) << {worker,{finished,aa}}
```

**Second run**:

```
15> A ! {self(),aa}.
(<0.100.0>) << {<0.76.0>,aa}
(<0.100.0>) <0.101.0> ! {request,{<0.76.0>,aa}}   //monitor receiveing message
{<0.76.0>,aa}
(<0.101.0>) << {request,{<0.76.0>,aa}}
16> (<0.106.0>) <0.62.0> ! {io_request,<0.106.0>,
                           #Ref<0.3226054513.2760638467.168007>,
                           {get_until,unicode,
                               ["16",62,32],
                               erl_scan,tokens,
                               [1,[text]]}}
```

As you can see from my trace , in the first call i do not understand what happens.Does my `worker` get timeouted and if so why ?

**P.S** The `frun` variable is used as a flag that is true only at the first `monitor` iteration so that when the first item arrives the process will call itself to process it (send it to the worker) since the worker is free of duty.
After the first run the `monitor` will dequeue items from the queue whenever the `worker` signals he is free.

**Update**

So after the helpful comments i have changed my logic a bit in the `monitor` so that the `worker` gets a message on the first run  , or , after he is done and notifies the `monitor` , there are still items in the queue of the `monitor`.
I still can't make it work.Where is the deadlock ?

```
monitor(MState=#monstate{wpid=W,free=F,wref=Ref,queue=Q,qc=C,frun=FirstRun})->
        receive
            {request,{From ,Message}} -> case FirstRun of
                                            true ->  W ! {From,Message},
                                                     monitor(MState#monstate{frun=false,free=false});                                                     
                                            false -> 
                                                     St=case tryEnqueue({From,Message},MState) of 
                                                           {queue_full,S} -> From ! {queue_full,Message},
                                                                             S;
                                                           {queued,S} -> S
                                                        end,
                                                     monitor(St)
                                             end;
                                                                        
            {worker,{finished,_}}-> case queue:out(Q) of
                                        {{_,Element},Rest} -> W ! Element,
                                                        monitor(MState#monstate{free=false,queue=Rest,qc=C-1});
                                        {empty,Rest} -> monitor(MState#monstate{free=true,queue=Rest})
                                    end;

        end.
```

Comment: Regarding the update, the deadlock is the same. I've updated the response with the deadlock sequence. Also, `W!Message` is missing the `From`

Comment: I see now your point , now it hit me.I put the dequeue-ing logic based on my worker but the worker could be free and the queue can keep gathering elements without it triggering anything.

Comment: I see now your point , now it hit me.I put the dequeue-ing logic based on my worker but the worker could be free and the queue can keep gathering elements without it triggering anything.I guess what i need is something like a blocking queue that blocks the process until it can dequeue something.This process being able to run standalone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `monitor` behavior need to depend on `frun`. It just needs to depend on whether `worker` is `free`. I have updated `monitor` function to reflect this in the following code.

```erlang
-module(mq).
-compile(export_all).

-record(monstate,{
    queue,
    qc,
    wpid,
    free=true,
    wref,
    init=false
}).
-record(sstate,{
    init=false,
    mpid=null,
    mref=null
}).

-define(QUEUE_SIZE,5).
-define(PROC_SLEEP,2000).


createProcess({M,F,A})->
    Pid=spawn(M,F,[A]),
    Ref=erlang:monitor(process,Pid),
    {Pid,Ref}.

start()->
    spawn(?MODULE,server,[#sstate{init=false}]).

server(State=#sstate{init=I})when I=:=false ->
    {MPid,MRef}=createProcess({?MODULE,monitor,#monstate{init=false}}),
    server(State#sstate{init=true,mpid=MPid,mref=MRef});

server(State=#sstate{mpid=MPid,mref=MRef})->
    receive
           {From,state}->From ! State,
                            server(State);
           {From,Message}-> MPid ! {request,{From,Message}},
                            server(State);

            {'DOWN',MRef,process,MPid,_}-> {NewMPid,NewMRef}=createProcess({?MODULE,monitor,#monstate{init=false}}),
                                            server(State#sstate{mpid=NewMPid,mref=NewMRef});
            _ ->exit(invalid_message)

    end.


tryEnqueue(Message,MState=#monstate{queue=Q,qc=C}) when C<?QUEUE_SIZE->
    NewQueue=queue:in(Message,Q),
    {queued,MState#monstate{qc=C+1,queue=NewQueue}};
tryEnqueue(_,MState)->{queue_full,MState}.

monitor(MState=#monstate{wpid=_,wref=_,init=I}) when I=:= false ->
    {WorkerPid,WorkerRef}=createProcess({?MODULE,worker,self()}),
    monitor(MState#monstate{wpid=WorkerPid,wref=WorkerRef,init=true,qc=0,queue=queue:new()});

monitor(MState=#monstate{wpid=W,free=F,wref=Ref,queue=Q,qc=C})->
  receive
    {request,{From ,Message}} ->
      %% check whether worker is free or not
      case F of
        true ->
          W ! {From,Message},
          monitor(MState#monstate{free=false});

        false ->
          St=case tryEnqueue({From,Message},MState) of
               {queue_full,S} ->
                 From ! {queue_full,Message},
                 S;
               {queued,S} -> S
             end,
          monitor(St)
      end;

    {worker,{finished,_}} ->
      case queue:out(Q) of
        {{_,Element},Rest} ->
          W ! Element,
          monitor(MState#monstate{free=false,queue=Rest,qc=C-1});

        {empty,Rest} ->
          monitor(MState#monstate{free=true,queue=Rest})
      end;

    {'DOWN',Ref,process,_,_} ->
      {NewWorkerPid,NewWorkerRef}=createProcess({?MODULE,worker,self()}),
      monitor(MState#monstate{wpid=NewWorkerPid,wref=NewWorkerRef,free=true});

    _->exit(invalid_message)

  end.

worker(MPid)->
  receive
    {From,MSG} ->
      timer:sleep(?PROC_SLEEP),
      From ! {processed,MSG},
      MPid ! {worker,{finished,MSG}},
      worker(MPid);
    _ ->exit(bad_msg)
  end.
```

**Usage**

```sh
Eshell V10.5  (abort with ^G)
1> c(mq).
mq.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,mq}
2> A=mq:start().
<0.92.0>
3> A ! {self(),aa}.
{<0.85.0>,aa}
4> flush().
Shell got {processed,aa}
ok
5> A ! {self(),aa}.
{<0.85.0>,aa}
6> flush().
Shell got {processed,aa}
ok
7> A ! {self(), aa}, A ! {self(), bb}.
{<0.85.0>,bb}
8> flush().                           
Shell got {processed,aa}
Shell got {processed,bb}
ok
9>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response ! I didn't really know how to create a loop on the queue to continue dequeue-ing.Your response is spot on.If the queue has items you loop on the `{worker,{finished,_}}` pattern .

Answer (score 1):

In your code, it seems that `frun` is always false after the first run:

```erlang
            case R of
                true -> self() ! {worker,{finished,R}},
                        monitor(NewState#monstate{frun=false});
                false -> monitor(NewState#monstate{frun=false})
            end;
```

Once it reaches `false`, no `{worker, {finished, R}}` message will be delivered and so no element will be extracted from the queue.

**Update: Deadlock sequence:**

1. Monitor receives first job and forwards it to the worker
2. Monitor's `frun` is false now
3. Worker performs the job
4. Worker notifies monitor that the job has finished
5. Since monitor's queue is empty, nothing happens.
6. Monitor receives second job, since `frun` is false, the job is not forwarded to the worker

Comment: Well that was the desired behaviour. When first running i want my `monitor` to signal to himself that there is an item queued in the queue so that it sends it to the `worker`.From then on the `worker` will act as the one that signals to the `monitor`.The `frun`(first run) serves as a flag to start the processing loop.

Comment: The only way the worker receives the second job is by receiving the `worker,{finished,_}}` message in the monitor, which happens only if the monitor has `frun = true` or if the worker finishes and there is something queued. If the worker finishes before something is added to the queue, it deadlocks. (You can check it with `A ! {self(), aa}, A ! {self(), bb}.`)

Comment: This is somewhat common in Erlang, if it's not an exercise, I'd recommend checking to see if any of the available libraries suit your project.

Comment: I went this route since , i wanted ideally the `monitor` to implement the `supervisor` behaviour but also `gen_server`. I wanted the `monitor` to deal both with `restart/shutdown` of the worker while also being able to get querried by external processes regarding the state of the `worker`

Comment: Since the solution is `worker`-driven (he updates the state of the monitor) what would the solution be without a flag like `frun` , since i want the `monitor` to send himself a message only on the first iteration.

Comment: Supervisors are already gen_servers, be careful with that. In the past I've treated the first position in the queue as the "in progress" position. So the monitor sends a job to the worker when the queue goes from 0 to 1 elements or when the worker finishes a job and there are queued jobs. The monitor'd not remove the first job from the queue until it's finished

Comment: Although it's more complex that what you're trying to do, you can check [this](https://github.com/Kuroneer/taskerl/blob/180fcb7ad6e6be76e2477a3021a1b23037f5b727/src/taskerl_gen_server_serializer.erl#L276-L288) for ideas